# How do I know «why» I gained or lost so many points in recalc?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I triggered rep recalc today and promptly lost around 40 points. I am not too concerned about these points, but I am still curious why I lost them. What I am interested in is a summary of the events that caused the net increase or decrease in rep; e.g.,

> - You lost 10 points because the user DisappearingAct deleted her account on  Jul 4.
> - This answer of yours was unaccepted.
> - This post, which you had downvoted, was deleted subsequently.

I do have access to the full list of rep changes [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation), but the information I am looking for is hard -- if not impossible -- to gather from that.

Is this obscurity by design? Or is there a feature that allows me to see this information?

Comment: related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2772 (tl;dr: there is no way to find out what happened)

Comment: I'm not even sure what the point of rep recalc is anyway. SE isn't the IRS -- if a user's rep is a little higher than it "should" be here, a little lower there, nobody (should) really care.

Comment: @user7530 Good point. On the other hand, I am also not sure why the rep recalc isn't done automatically. Why should I have to push a button?

Comment: Oh it's _not_ automatic? Where's the button?

Comment: @user7530 Click the link in the post and go to the bottom of the page. =) ///  I am not sure whether recalc will be triggered automatically every so often if you never manually trigger it.

Comment: Recalc *is* done automatically now and then. It is a "Fool me once, shame on you, etc." situation if you manually recalc more than once to lose your points more quickly.

Comment: Wow.  I clicked on recalc and promptly lost 9 points.  To those who may want to try it:  don't!

Answer (score 4):

The reputation number is denormalized so it is standard for it to be slightly out of date due to unusual events like users getting deleted, posts getting deleted (either self-deleted by their owner or due to some other reason), posts getting migrated to other Stack Exchange sites, and so forth.

The reputation is brought in line by periodic recalculations, which happen sporadically. You can also trigger one yourself if you like.

I wouldn't be concerned about deviations of a percent or so.

Comment: I am more curious than concerned. :) Thanks for your answer.